# How to topologically sort installed rpm packages?

Tags: fedora, rpm, dnf

I want to sort topologically, according to dependencies, all installed rpm packages on my Fedora with most required packages to be on top (for example glibc) and least required packages to be on bottom. I can list all installed packages with `rpm -qa`, but they don't seem to be topologically sorted.

My goal is to review installed packages, find the ones I don't need anymore and uninstall them.

Comment: You might find `package-cleanup  --leaves` useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a bit, it seems that `rpmdep` tool from `rpmorphan` package is the most close to what I want. To see the most required installed packages, it can be run with `--depending` option:

```
rpmdep -all --depending | tac | less -S
```

Answer (score 3):

[man rpmgraph:](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=3501818)

```
rpmgraph(8) - Linux man page
Name
rpmgraph - Display RPM Package Dependency Graph
Synopsis

rpmgraph PACKAGE_FILE ...
Description

rpmgraph uses PACKAGE_FILE arguments to generate a package dependency graph. Each
PACKAGE_FILE argument is read and added to an rpm transaction set. The elements 
of the transaction set

are partially ordered using a topological sort.

The partially ordered elements are then printed to standard output.


Nodes in the dependency graph are package names, and edges in the directed graph 
point to the parent of each node. The parent node is defined as the last 
predecessor of a package when partially ordered using the package dependencies as
a relation. That means that the parent of a given package is the package's last
prerequisite.

The output is in dot(1) directed graph format, and can be displayed or printed
using the dotty graph editor from the graphviz package. There are no rpmgraph
specific options, only common rpm options. See the rpmgraph usage message for    
what is currently implemented. 

  [1]: https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpmgraph
```

### Installation:

[rpm-devel fedora 19 has this package](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=3501818)

[Here is rpm-devel for fedora 30](https://pkgs.org/download/rpm-devel)

Use your package manager:

```
dnf install rpm-devel
```

To install `wget` in `CentOS`, enter the following in a terminal window:

```
sudo yum install wget
```

To install `wget` in `Fedora`, enter the following:

```
sudo dnf install wget
```

Now, you can use the wget command to download the .rpm file you want. Enter the following:

```
wget http://some_website/sample_file.rpm
```

The system should reach out to the website and download the file to your current working directory.

### Install RPM File Using RPM Command

To install a .rpm package in `Fedora` or `CentOS` Linux, enter the following:

```
sudo rpm –i sample_file.rpm
```

The –i switch tells the package manager you want to install the file.

More information on the RPM installer can be found in the [RPM documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm).

### Install RPM File With Yum

Alternately, you can use the `yum` package manager to install `.rpm` files.

Enter the following:

```
sudo yum localinstall sample_file.rpm
```

The `localinstall` option instructions yum to look at your current working directory for the installation file.

---

https://superuser.com/questions/483307/how-do-i-know-dependent-rpms-of-a-a-package

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-rpm-file-centos-linux

https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm

### EDIT:

I can't get `rpmgraph` to work, I've tried three different versions of `PACKAGE_FILE` syntax of package list, but it just gives errors, If you know how to use this program, please provide an answer or edit mine. Tested on `Fedora 28`.[How to list all installed packages with the .rpm extension. Fedora, Centos, RedHat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523104/how-to-list-all-installed-packages-with-the-rpm-extension-fedora-centos-redh)

```
# rpmgraph INSTALLED_PACKAGES 
(null): read manifest failed:
```

Comment: Is https://github.com/htgoebel/rpmgraph the upstream, I wonder? Appears to be a single python file, there.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm not sure, but what I can see it's not `This utility is slightly different from the one coming with RPM:`, hadn't seen that one thanks

Comment: But `rpmgraph` requires package files as arguments and generates a graph for these package files. I would like to get a topologically sorted list of all _installed_ packages.

Comment: @ks1322 yes that's something you can use this for, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote myself a script for this, but I hardly ever used it.

I'd handle removals with care.  I once tried to delete a package called "SimplyHTML" because it came up as a "leaf node", and when I went to remove it, found that "freemind" (a mind-mapping tool I use a lot) needed it and got deleted also.  Very weird!

Anyway, FWIW here's the script (which on my system is called "leaf-rpms"):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;
use Data::Dumper;

# a leaf RPM is one that has no deps and you can safely delete

# run it as is, delete any that you think are useless

my @installed = `rpm -qa --queryformat="%{NAME}\n"`;
chomp(@installed);
my %count;

@ARGV = ("dnf repograph |");

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^digraph packages/;
    next unless m({) .. m(});
    next if m({) or m(});

    s/"//g;
    $count{$_}++;
}
# print Dumper \@installed;
# print Dumper \@all;
# print Dumper \%count;
# print "----\n";

my %dup;
for my $k (sort @installed) {
    next if $dup{$k}++;
    print "$k\n" unless exists $count{$k};
}
```