# How to list all installed packages with the .rpm extension. Fedora, Centos, RedHat

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm

**How do I get a list of all installed packages with the `.rpm` extension?**

I am testing this on a Fedora 28.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a query format, eliminating the `sed` and the temporary file.

```
rpm --queryformat "%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}.rpm\n" -qa
```

Example output:

```
python3-decorator-4.3.0-2.fc30.noarch.rpm
webkit2gtk3-2.24.2-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm
tuned-2.11.0-1.fc30.noarch.rpm
nftables-0.9.0-5.fc30.x86_64.rpm
perl-encoding-2.22-10.fc30.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
rpm -qa > INSTALLED_PACKAGES
```

I found that I can append `.rpm` as SUFFIX to each line in the `INSTALLED_PACKAGES` file

```
sed 's/$/.rpm/' INSTALLED_PACKAGES
```

this way I have the extension.

Result:

```
librados2-12.2.12-1.fc28.x86_64.rpm
dconf-0.28.0-1.fc28.x86_64.rpm
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.10.10-1.fc28.x86_64.rpm
claws-mail-plugins-vcalendar-3.16.0-1.fc28.x86_64.rpm
python3-firewall-0.5.5-1.fc28.noarch.rpm
dhcping-1.2-19.fc28.x86_64.rpm
xorg-x11-server-common-1.19.6-10.fc28.x86_64.rpm
NetworkManager-l2tp-1.2.12-1.fc28.x86_64.rpm
perl-HTML-Parser-3.72-11.fc28.x86_64.rpm
shared-mime-info-1.10-1.fc28.x86_64.rpm
libblockdev-lvm-2.16-2.fc28.x86_64.rpm
xfce4-power-manager-1.6.1-2.fc28.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: On Fedora 37, `rpm -qa` is enough.