# rpmgraph: https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpmgraph USAGE and capabilities, Fedora, CentOs, RedHat

Tags: centos, fedora, package-management, rpm

PROBLEM:

**I'm trying to get this program running, I want to make a topological map/graph of the dependencies and packages on a `rpm` system:**

[rpm-devel-4.14.2-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm Fedora 29 Download](https://fedora.pkgs.org/29/fedora-x86_64/rpm-devel-4.14.2-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm.html)
gives amongst other things:

**/usr/bin/rpmgraph**. /usr/include/rpm/argv.h. /usr/include/rpm/header.h. /usr/include/rpm/rpmarchive.h. /usr/include/rpm/rpmbase64.h. /usr/include/rpm/rpmbuild.h.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpmgraph

```
rpmgraph PACKAGE_FILE
```

I've tried this:

```
rpm -qa > INSTALLED_PACKAGES
rpmgraph INSTALLED_PACKAGES
```

And this for populating `PACKAGE_FILE`:

```
rpm -qa | sort | sed -e 's/\([^.]*\).*/\1/' -e 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' > PACKAGE_FILE
```

this one is for only filename without all the version and architecture numbers.

With only filename I get these errors:

```
error: open of xfce4-screenshooter failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfce4-screenshooter-plugin failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfce4-session failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfce4-session-engines failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfce4-settings failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfce4-taskmanager failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfce4-terminal failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfce-polkit failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfconf failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfdesktop failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfsprogs failed: No such file or directory
error: open of xfwm4 failed: No such file or directory
```

and with the former I get this error:

```
# rpmgraph INSTALLED_PACKAGES 
(null): read manifest failed:
```

---

So I was assuming I need the list with the package + the `.rpm` extension like most `rpm` tools use for working with the package, but it didn't work.

QUESTION:

### Does anybody know if it's possible to make a map/graph like this of all installed packages with this program(`rpmgraph`) and if it is how?

Also if there was another way, please provide an answer?

I'm testing on a Fedora 30.

This question is related to this:[how-to-topologically-sort-installed-rpm-packages/523075#523075](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523064/how-to-topologically-sort-installed-rpm-packages/523075#523075)

EDIT:

I've tried this from the answer:

```
rpmgraph | rpm --queryformat "%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}.rpm\n" -qa > rpmgraph.dot
```

and then:

```
dot -Tps rpmgraph.dot -o rpmgraph.ps
```

But it gives these errors:

```
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '-20.f' in line 1794 of rpmgraph.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '-9.11.' in line 1795 of rpmgraph.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '-5.P' in line 1795 of rpmgraph.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '-2.12.' in line 1796 of rpmgraph.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '-2.f' in line 1796 of rpmgraph.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '-1.1.' in line 1797 of rpmgraph.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '-5.f' in line 1797 of rpmgraph.dot splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '-0.8.' in line 1798 of rpmgraph.dot splits into two tokens
```

And:

```
# dotty rpmgraph.dot 
graph parser: syntax error near line 1
context:  >>> giflib <<< -5.1.9-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm
dotty.lefty: cannot load graph
```

Comment: From what I understand about the `rpmgraph` software, is you have to use it on actual `rpm` package files and does not work with just a list from `rpmdb`.  To get a full dependency tree, you would run `rpmgraph` on all the `rpm` packages in the Fedora repository or make sure to have a directory of all your installed `rpm` packages that you could run `rpmgraph` on.  The `rpmgraph` software does not output a visual graph, but outputs `dot` directed graph format which can be parsed with the `dotty` graph editor.

Answer (score -1):

To generate graph you can try dot utility.

```
$ rpmgraph *.rpm > rpmgraph.dot
$ dot -Tps rpmgraph.dot -o rpmgraph.ps
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, I can't get a graph from the commands you provided, can you be more specific, thanks

Comment: rpmgraph output will be in dot directed graph format, and can be displayed or printed using the `dotty` graph editor from the `graphviz` package, https://linux.die.net/man/1/dot

Comment: -1 I can't get this to work and I can't find any dotty graph editor in the link you provided

Comment: I thought you asked for explanation only you can download it from here https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/